# change innertext without affecting dom elements in Javascript (not jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xul

I need this inside a firefox extension, so I am not using Jquery, here is my code:

```
var label = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "label"); // create a new XUL label
  label.setAttribute("value", actionLabel);
  label.setAttribute("class", "label-title");
  var description = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "description"); 
  description.setAttribute("id", actionId);
  description.appendChild(label);
  description.innerHTML=actionText;
```

Output should be:

```
<description id=actionId> <label class="label-title" value=actionLabel/> This is a long section of text that will word wrap when displayed. </description>
```

Comment: You can use .innerText and/or .textContent, see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t07

Answer (score 0):

This did the job:

description.insertBefore(label,description.firstChild);